# VS Code Debugging problems after last update (1.69.2)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, unbound

After the last update of VS Code to version 1.69.2 i am not able to debug my nodejs - express, project. I am getting unbound breakpoints when i am adding them. My launch.json file :

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "request": "attach",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "node",
        "sourceMaps": false
    }
    ]
}
```

When i am trying to "troubleshoot the launch configuration" i am getting the error message from vs code : "it looks like your degug session has already ended......" but it is not, it is active.

In my project i am using nodejs - express - javascript mostly (no Typescript thats why i set sourceMaps to false).

I am starting my project with the command :
node --inspect sever.js
and after that i attach by procces the debugger ( to default 127.0.0.1:9229).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? What has change after the last update and i can't use the degugging of VS Code?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Download a previous version.
Also, disable auto updates from Settings -> Update.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is something wrong with the last update of VS code? Are they working on it to solve the problem? Did you have a similar problem?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the latest version. So try using the previous version. I'm sure the VSCode team is working on another update. Many seem to be having similar issues.